# How can I block all ports except 443 on MacOS Catalina

Tags: macos, macos-catalina

For test reasons I want to temporarily block all ports on MacOS Catalina except 443. How can I do / undo this?

Comment: This is not a programming question. Please address it to either the [Super User](https://superuser.com/) or [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/) sites. The latter is Apple-specific. Unless your question is how to modify the firewall settings from within your program, in which case you should update the question to state so.

Comment: You can play with Little Snitch: https://www.obdev.at/products/littlesnitch/index.html - I think it's free for some period of time (trial mode), so you can use it in case you need to test something for like few days.

Comment: This worked for me (based on pfctl): https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/380010/how-can-i-block-all-ports-except-443-on-macos-catalina